# Display and edit the value stored in the SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Help please, I'm a bit lost, new to all this and trying to learn.
I want to store 3 names and phone numbers in SharedPreferences and display them in individual textviews so a user can edit the name and phone number and also press the number to call the number.

What I have so far is:

```
public void setWardenName(Context context, String key, String value) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString(getString(R.string.), Name);
            editor.apply();
    }
    public void getWardenName(Context context, String prefKey) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name = preferences.getString("Name", "");
        if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            name = name;
        }
    }
```

And on the activity screen I have the first texview called:

`android:id="@+id/textView2"` which was going to be the first name.

So I'm lost, any help is appreciated.

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what to put in this line here: editor.putString(getString(R.string.NOT SURE ABOUT HERE), Name);

Comment: And I don't know how to get it to display in the textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will set the Warden as your key name and it depends on you if you want to change that. And, I will assume that it is in the same class since you are using 'this' in

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

So here it is..

```
private void setWarden(String value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("Warden", value);
    editor.commit();
}


private String getWarden() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name = sharedPref.getString("Warden", "");
    if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
        return name;            
        }
    return "";
}
```

And in your textview you can get it like:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv.setText(getWarden());
```